# How to fit image size to screen while using scrollview in android

Tags: android, imageview, scrollview

I am using an image wrapped inside scrollview and horizontal scrollview with wrap_content.The size of image is larger than the screen size and the content overflows the screen enabling the scrolls.
How can i make it fit the screen  and only enable scroll when i want ( when i am zooming the image).

PS: webview does not fit my requirements.

Comment: Could you show a screenshot of what is going on?

Comment: maybe you should get the screen resolution at runtime and set it to your ImageView height and width.